# 500 internal server error on server, works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

How do I go about tracking down an error when all `production.log` gives me is this?

```
11:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
12:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
13:     <%= yield(:head) %>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4417234491726047977_45250520'
app/controllers/docs_controller.rb:27:in `index'
Processing by ErrorsController#broken as HTML
Rendered errors/broken.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms
```

FYI: the line 10 of `application.html.erb` is `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>` so I'm assuming it has something to do with either my CSS or my gemfile. How do I investigate it further?

Also, my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'json', '1.7.7'
gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'steak'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

gem 'sass'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise', '>= 2.1.2'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'yaml_db'
gem 'passenger'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'truncate_html'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'whenever'
gem 'impressionist'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts_as_indexed'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'public_activity'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gemfile needed `uglifier`, which was imported with an old version of another gem.

```
gem 'uglifier'
```

fixed it.